# leftShift method on BigInteger in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, biginteger

How to perform a *leftShift* operation on a *BigInteger* in **Groovy**?

The *leftShift* method is defined in [Groovy's JDK enhancement](//docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#leftShift(java.lang.Number,java.lang.Number))

However, the below code throws an *UnsupportedOperationException* exception:

```
Integer i = new Integer(3)
println(i << 2)

BigInteger b = new BigInteger("3")
println(b << 2)
```

Result:

```
12   <-- working for Integer
Caught: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot use leftShift() on this number type: java.math.BigInteger with value: 3
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot use leftShift() on this number type: java.math.BigInteger with value: 3
        at test.run(test.groovy:5)
```

I suppose I could use the [BigInteger.shiftLeft()](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#shiftLeft-int-) method (note it's not *leftShift* but *shiftLeft*...), but in the end, I would like to use the `<<` operator on a *Number*, which could be either an *Integer* or a *BigInteger*.

Bug in Groovy? (I'm using 3.0.4)

Comment: Does that work: `Number n = new BigInteger("3"); println(n << 2)`?

Comment: This is static method, to use like `DefaultGroovyMethods.leftShift()` I'd say

Comment: @seelenvirtuse ```Number n = new BigInteger("3"); println(n << 2)``` throws the same exception

Comment: Conclusion: this **was** a bug in Groovy (for a long time), and it will be fixed in versions 4.0, 3.0.5 and 2.5.13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason the underlying [`BigIntegerMath`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/BigIntegerMath.java) does not override the [leftShiftImpl()](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/NumberMath.java#L256) method, which results in an `UnsopportedOperationException`.

Might be worth to file an issue.

For now you have to resort to workarounds like

```
assert 12 == new BigInteger(3).intValue() << 2
//or
assert 12 == new BigInteger(3).shiftLeft( 2 )
```

Comment: That workaround would break with any truly Big integer

Comment: Thank you, I reported the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9605

Comment: And we already have a [PR to fix the problem](https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/1287)! My goodness, it took less than 24 hours from the moment I asked on SO...

Answer (score 1):

So, this seems to be a bug in Groovy, as pointed our by @injecteer

The good news is that Groovy is easily "fix-able" with class "mixin":

```
class EnhancedNumber {

    static def originalLeftShift = org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.&leftShift
    static Number leftShift(Number self, Number operand) {
        self.class == BigInteger ? self.shiftLeft(operand) : originalLeftShift(self, operand)
    }
}

Number.mixin(EnhancedNumber)

Integer i = new Integer(3)
assert 12 == i << 2

Number b = new BigInteger("3")
assert 12 == b << 2
```

Still a bit annoying though...